# Chi distribution probability calculation

Tags: probability

I am trying to perform a McNemar Test and due to the design of my model, I have the square root of the chi-square value (instead of chi-square value). Now, how do I calculate the p-value from the chi value?

Comment: Square the chi-statistic to get chi-sq statistic. Then use software to get the P-value from the chi-squared dist'n (or printed tables to bracket the P-value as closely as possible). // If df = 5, chi-stat = 3.2, P-value for right-tailed test obtained in R using code: `1 - pchisq(3.2^2,  5)` returns P-value 0.06871364. In R, `pchisq` is CDF of chi-squared dist'n. With typical printed table you might only be able to bracket P-val as btw 0.05 and 0.10. // Or maybe you have stat calculator. Read instructions. See if you can get same answer I got using R.

Comment: Thanks! I found out another way. Square root of Chi-square(df=n) follows chi(df=n) distribution. So we can use chi(n) distribution to get the probabilities. There is a package in R called ‘chi’ which gives the chi(n) probabilities. The result is the same as yours.

Comment: Glad you found something that works.